# git merge and commit is pushing multiple review on repo

Tags: git, gerrit

We have two git repository A and git repository B .
I wanted to keep all the history of repository A and wanted to commit on repositoryB. 
I ran below command. It created all RepositoryA git commit as new commit.

Steps:
git remote add RemoteA path/of/repositoryA

git fetch RemoteA

git merge branch/ofRepository

git push origin HEAD:refs/for/RepositoryB

How can I delete all the commit from the repo server.

Comment: You have to specify more details about what the server is. It seems like you've pushed more than you wanted but the fix necessarily has to be server-side; or you have to push the original commit with `git push -f`

Comment: I don't have access of serve side, ** git push -f ** need direct push permission. Is there any other way I can revert all these commit.

Comment: No.      You cannot.

Answer (score 1):

I think It is not needed to push commits from repoA to review branch in repoB. So just push them directly to the remote branch. For this you need [direct push permission](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push) on that branch. `git push origin <branch>`